# My iPad2 will not print to my HP wifi printer since the IOS8 update

Tags: wifi

Can anyone advise me why my previously working HP printer and IPAD2 connection has suddenly stopped working after the recent IOS8 software update and how to rectify it? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by 'suddenly stopped working'? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it has stopped working. You should file a bug report with Apple. In the meantime, I use an app on my Mac Mini called HandyPrint which allows iOS devices to print wirelessly to non-Airport printers and I suspect this might resolve your issue.